# Allow job to run "reboot" command without causing failure

Tags: gitlab-ci

We have a large number of runners running a large number of jobs in one of our Gitlab CI/CD pipelines.

Each of these runners has a `concurrency` of `1`, and they are of `executor` type `shell`.

[EDIT] These runners are AWS EC2 instances using Amazon Linux 2.

After certain jobs in the pipeline have completed, I would like them to run a `reboot` command to restart the runner.

However, some of these jobs will be tests. Currently, when I run the `reboot` command, the job fails. Obviously I can `allow_failure` so that the job passes, but this then means we have no way of determining whether or not the actual test has passed.

Originally, my test job looked like this:

```
after_script:
  - sleep 1 && reboot
```

I have also tried the following variations:

```
after_script:
  - sleep 15 && reboot
  - exit 0

after_script:
  - (sleep 15 ; reboot ) &
  - exit 0
```

I've also tried running a shell script with the same contents.

All of these result in the same problem - `ERROR: Job failed (system failure): aborted: terminated`.

Can anyone think of a clever way round this?

Comment: Something like `shutdown +1`, to shut down in one minute? If you manage to tell the system to shut down with a delay with a command that returns immediately, then the GitLab script should have time to finish before the system restarts. I'm not sure which command does this though.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to achieve with `sleep` and the `( cmd ) &` syntax. Neither appears to work in the pipeline though.

Comment: If you run a sleep command then your pipeline should stop for 15 seconds, and then call the next command. If that command is reboot, the machine should start shutting down things immediately, and the pipeline doesn't finish. If you manage to start a program outside of the pipeline, it should be possible to have the machine restart after the pipeline finishes. What are you running your runners on? Normal servers, virtual machines, docker containers, something else? Which operating system?

Comment: Hi @MrBerta, thank you, I've updated my OP to include this information - the runners are AWS EC2 instances using Amazon Linux 2. I'm afraid the `( syntax )` isn't working, so I'm looking for other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to run this in a screen:

`sudo screen -dm bash -c 'sleep 5; shutdown -r now;'`

This allowed me, in a Gitlab CI pipeline, to run this as a `script` element, and immediately afterwards execute an `exit` command, like this:

```
after_script:
  - sudo screen -dm bash -c 'sleep 5; shutdown -r now;'
  - exit 0
```

This way, if a test fails - the job fails. If a test passes, the job passes. No need for `allow_failure`.

Unfortunately... I'm unsure of how to then contend with `artifacts` which take place after the `after_script` commands. If anyone has any ideas about that one, please add a comment here.

Comment: If the job needs to upload artifacts, maybe the reboot step should be in a subsequent stage instead. But why do you need to reboot the runners?

Comment: Unfortunately the `artifacts` stage on Gitlab is always processed last, after `after_script`. We're encountering performance issues throughout the day; not sure why yet (getting the metrics sorted now), but the restarts are a quick fix.

Comment: I mean move the reboot command to a separate stage as its own job (where the reboot is the only thing it does). CI can have multiple stages: e.g. lint, build, test, and in your case til you get it figured out you can have one final stage called reboot where the only script is the above script. That way, if the build or test stages need to upload artifacts, they can. The last stage won't run until these stages are complete (including the artifact upload)